# mySQL - Query to count rows and total percentage too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance, query-performance

Table named 'log', currently it has 50 million rows:

```
| id     | domainIP        |
| foo    | 158.132.34.5    |
| bob    | 128.12.244.3    |
| bob    | 128.12.244.3    |
| bob    | 19.152.134.4    |
| bob    | 168.152.34.9    |
| alice  | 178.132.64.10   |
| alice  | 188.152.214.200 |
| peter  | 208.162.36.153  |
| peter  | 208.162.36.153  |
| peter  | 208.162.36.153  |
| peter  | 198.168.94.201  |
```

I have the following query, to get the number of times `id` was used with each 'domainIP', and the percentage of each:

```
SELECT
    `log`.`id`,
    `log`.`domainIP`,
    COUNT(`log`.`domainIP`) AS "Times",
    totalsTable.Totals,
    (COUNT(`log`.`domainIP`)/totalsTable.Totals)*100 AS "Percentage"
FROM `log`
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        `id`,
        COUNT(`domainIP`) AS Totals
    FROM `log` GROUP BY `id`
    ) AS totalsTable

ON (`log`.`id` = totalsTable.`id`)

GROUP BY `log`.`domainIP` ORDER BY `log`.`id` ASC, "Percentage"  DESC
```

It returns:

```
| id     | domainIP        | Times | Totals | Percentage
| foo    | 158.132.34.5    | 1     | 1      | 100
| bob    | 128.12.244.3    | 2     | 4      | 50
| bob    | 19.152.134.4    | 1     | 4      | 25
| bob    | 168.152.34.9    | 1     | 4      | 25
| alice  | 178.132.64.10   | 1     | 2      | 50
| alice  | 188.152.214.200 | 1     | 2      | 50
| peter  | 208.162.36.153  | 3     | 4      | 75
| peter  | 198.168.94.201  | 1     | 4      | 25
```

The result is exactly I need, but it's unusable slow (takes several minutes).

Here's the table structure exported from phpmyadmin.

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `eDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `domainIP` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `log`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `logUnique` (`id`,`eDate`,`event`),
  ADD KEY `eDate` (`eDate`),
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`,`eDate`),
  ADD KEY `event` (`id`,`eDate`,`event`);
```

Results of EXPLAIN query on a smaller version of the table:

```
id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys      | key       | key_len | ref            | rows  | Extra
1 | PRIMARY | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL               | NULL      | NULL    | NULL           | 100   | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
1 | PRIMARY | log        | ref   | logUnique,id,event | logUnique | 453     | totalsTable.id | 1     |  
2 | DERIVED | log        | index | NULL               | id        | 459     | NULL           | 100   |
```

**I need to formulate a query that returns the same thing but that is usable (returns results in a manner of seconds, not minutes), but don't know how**

Note: adding an index to domainIP only slightly improves the response of a small size sample, but the full table still takes more than 10 minutes to return the result.

The table was created for other purposes, and i'd prefer to modify it's structure the least possible if anything at all.

Comment: Putting aside the fact that table is absolutely horribly designed, what you can do is allow your MySQL to use more RAM - this is done by using `InnoDB` as storage engine and increasing the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` system variable. Since you're using PHPMyAdmin and since your table is structured awfully like that, I'll make a guess that you're running default settings, which are there so MySQL can run on super-old hardware. Now, as for why table is horribly designed - it's not really relevant, what you want to do is shift I/O from disk to RAM, hence increasing the value of that var.

Comment: @Mjh i'll take a look at that. Originally this table was designed for a completely different purpose, many years ago, this is a feature i need to add just now, i'm not about to redesing such a table for such a small new requirement.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, we've all faced such an issue at one point. Anyway, what you'll be doing is taking the slowness of hard disk out of equation and rely on RAM's read I/O to supply CPU with info. The actual workload will be the same, with difference that the computer will read from faster storage. Usually, that's the magic hammer with MySQL and bad queries. Ensure you don't overdo it with the `innodb_buffer_pool_value`.

Comment: Keys `id` and `event` are redundant with `logunique`; drop those two.  Promote `UNIQUE logunique` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 2):

You may find that this is a bit faster.  Start with this version:

```
SELECT l.id, l.domainIP, COUNT(*) as Times,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log l2 WHERE l2.id = l.id) as Total
FROM log l
GROUP BY l.id, l.domainIP
ORDER BY l.id ASC;
```

Your existing index starting with `id` should be sufficient.

Actually, you can even remove the correlated subquery to measure the performance of just the `GROUP BY`.  If it is not good enough, then you basically know that you cannot improve your more complicated query.  You will need to try some other method, such as using triggers to maintain the total counts.

Comment: this performs a lot faster than my query, but still it seems not enough. it takes 0.05s for 10000 rows. the time for 50million (even if it where a linear relation) is a lot still. I also performed the GROUP BY alone, and it takes a very long time as well, so the problem seems the be even before the subquery. i guess this table is just too big.

Comment: @ndelucca . . . Or your hardware is too small ;)  If the `GROUP BY` is too slow, then you may need another solution, such as using triggers to calculate the summaries when data changes.

Answer (score 1):

Looking briefly, it's not a surprise that queries take such huge time, because there's `varchar` non-unique *id* and `varchar` *domainIP*. String comparing can be slower than comparing `int` fields in many orders of magnitude. You should consider to make denormalization:

1. *id* field must unique identifier, `longint`, for example;
2. you should declare table like `user_names` of `id` and `user_name`. Then you should declare table like 'user_ips' consisting of `id`, `user_id` (which is actually an id from `user_names`) and `domainIP`.

Only this few changes must increase query speed significantly. Hopefully, this will help you a bit

Comment: Comparing and coercing data types is many orders of magnitude **faster** than the underlying I/O issue OP's having. Your answer doesn't reflect on that, instead it just focuses on comparing oranges with apples and denormalization, something which he asked not to do. I won't vote on your answer, but it's only half-correct.

Comment: The question was about how to increase query speed. I make a simple conclusion which has a side effect in better DB structure as well. This will not be redundant considering that man who ask a question said about table restructuring.
I actually talk about this:
`SELECT
        id,
        COUNT(domainIP) AS Totals
    FROM log GROUP BY id`
Grouping works using comparing column values which is a string. Please, tell me if i'm wrong

Comment: I read the question, this is what OP wrote: `and i'd prefer to modify it's structure the least possible if anything at all`, you're suggesting changing structure. I wrote my comment, and it seems you either didn't read anything or didn't understand what's written. To compare whatever to whatever, you need to **read** it first from **somewhere**. In this case it's reading from **hard drive**, which is slowest component in a computer. So, no matter how you denormalize or optimize your tables, in the end they need to be _read_ from somewhere. If that _somewhere_ is slow, conclude.

Comment: Hence, suggesting only one optimization (alter structure, write a better query) is, sadly, half the answer to achieve speed.

Comment: @Mjh . . . Apart from whether the changes to the data structure are a good idea, they are not going to have a noticeable impact on performance -- in particular, they will not change a query that goes from minutes to a few seconds.